# Implicit vs explicit casting operator best practices

Tags: c#, casting

I've recently discovered the casting operator in C#. Now I know I can override the operator to allow either:

```
byte b1 = new Foo();
byte b2 = (byte) new Foo();
```

But from the point of view of a `Foo` consumer I don't know which would be easier to understand that a conversion can be made. I'm specifically thinking on junior programmers who would/will have to maintain my code in the future (or what myself would have thought if I had seen this just some days ago).

On the one hand implicit casting looks a bit weird. It looks like assigning different, uncompatible types. And the IDE's intellisense won't tell you there's a method that can do that without the compiler complaining.

ON the other hand, explicit casting looks like forcing the conversion. Ok, it's a way of telling the compiler "I know what I'm doing, don't grumble". But how would a programmer with no access to `Foo`'s code (or no knowledge that casting operators exist in C#) that the casting can be performed and do something expected?

Which of the types of casting is preferred in which situations? Is there a third way?

Comment: I would use implicit casting only when there is no loss of information like from `int` to `long`.

Comment: It depends on context, otherwise its about opinion.

Comment: I would just extend a suggestion: Don't structure your code to accommodate juniors, just make sure it is clean, easy to read and well documented, future developers should be able to read your comments in code and work out that it is a cast, and *why* you are casting it.

Comment: @DanielDawes, I would proffer it's nothing to do with juniors.  Code should be readable and obvious without referring to documentation, in my opinion (some complex scenarios accepting, of course).  At first glance, and depending on what `Foo` actually is, the above code is confusing in both cases.  Mufaka's answer below (a `ToByte` method) makes perfect sense and shows intent.

Comment: @Moo-Juice I mean _juniors_ as well as _myself just 1 week ago_, before knowing the existence of the casting operator.

Comment: @Moo-Juice I absolutely agree, I mentioned juniors because J.A.I.L. had specifically said about juniors maintaining his code. I do frequently add summary and param doc to my methods though, just because it's easier later on when referring back to large systems to get back into the code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `Foo` is obviously numeric in nature, and the conversion is widening then an implicit conversion is useful to the consumer.

If the conversion is narrowing then the operator should be explicit.

---

If `Foo` is not numeric (and `Foo` really isn't) then it should not be castable to a numeric type.

Implement some other method or property that will perform an operation to convert the `Foo` instance to a numeric type. The name of that function should give semantic meaning to the caller, describing the value returned and any operation performed to return it.

---

You shouldn't avoid parts of a programming language because readers may not understand. You should comment your code, using simple prose, to explain your decisions and why you have made them. Explain how to use your types to their maximum advantage.

Use the features of the language that map best to the information system you are modelling. Who knows, readers might learn something.

Comment: This is explaining why my intuition is telling me in some cases the implicit casting is ok and in other looks odd.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the second one is more readable in your case. The operations underlying both are the same.

Note that you could also write :

```
var b2 = (byte) new Foo();
```

which I think, would be best if readability's considered.

**How?** -

1. You're using `byte` only once.
2. You're letting the "future programmers" know that you're casting `Foo` and that type of b2 is `byte` in one go using `(byte)`

Comment: `Foo` is a very generic case.